# Need to return result of for loop as lambda result

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS lambda; I have to return the result of my for loop as result of the lambda function,

Below code will be giving users who have not used there AWS password for last 60 days; it has been tested in the jupyter notebook and its working fine

```
import json
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

    resource = boto3.resource('iam')
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    for user in resource.users.all():
        if user.password_last_used is not None:
            delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
            if delta > 60:
                print("username: ", [user.user_name][0]," - ",delta , "days")
```

How can I return the result as below output from the jupyter notebook

```
Username: abc- 96 Days 
Username: def- 64 Days 
Username: ghi- 184 Days
Username: mno- 158 Days 
Username: xyz- 95 Days
```

Lambda code which I tried to append output to an array and return the array but returning Null:-

```
import json
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    resource = boto3.resource('iam')
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    userName = []
    for user in resource.users.all():
        if user.password_last_used is not None:
            delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
            if delta > 30:
                userName.append("username: ", [user.user_name][0]," - ",delta , "days")

    return userName
```

Comment: Can you just return an array of strings? Instead of printing out the output, just append the strings you are printing to an array and return that array.

Comment: its returning null , if i try to return instead for print @RedCricket

Comment: i also tried to create array and append output of loop to array, and to return that array its returing empty array

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    resource = boto3.resource('iam')
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    for user in resource.users.all():
        if user.password_last_used is not None:
            delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
            if delta > 30:
                userName.append("username: ", [user.user_name][0]," - ",delta , "days")
                
    return userName

Comment: No edit your question to include the code you tried.

Comment: done@RedCricket

Comment: don't declare `userName` to be global. Declare local to `lambda_handler()`

Comment: yes i removed it still no output

Comment: output :- Response:
[]

Request ID:
"6cf7681d-c449-11e8-a601-ff6f4afdb5a3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you are appending the results. Append does not take comma separated values like print does. Use the following line to make it work.

```
userName.append(f"username: {[user.user_name][0]}- {delta} days")
```

or the following if you are using python 2

```
userName.append("username: {}- {} days".format([user.user_name][0],delta))
```

Also make sure that the policy allows both IAM:GetUser and IAM:ListUsers

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    resource = boto3.resource('iam')
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    sns = boto3.client('sns')
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    physicalString ='Below users not logged into AWS console for 90 days\n'
    final_report = ''
    final_result = ''
    number =int(1)
    for user in resource.users.all():
        if user.password_last_used is not None:
            delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
        if delta >= 0:
            final_result= str(number) + " username: "+ [user.user_name][0]+" - "+str(delta) + "days\n"
            final_report = final_report+final_result
            number=number+1
    response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:XXXXXXXXXXXX:AWS_KMSKEY',
        Message= physicalString + final_report,
        Subject='IAM USER'
    )
```

above code is working we are able to get list of users output as below:-

```
1 username: abc- 102days
2 username: efg- 190days
3 username: zyz- 164days
```